# Corporate Finance Vs Corporate Finance? (w/ context differences)

Tags: canada, financial-literacy, terminology

I've heard corporate finance in 2 very different contexts, one referring to IBD, S&T, PE, VC and hedge funds, the other referring to a more financial accounting oriented role (at the same level w/ internal audit, treasury, FP&A)

- What's the difference?
- Why are they called the same?
- How do I know which one someone's referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Context is everything; these aren't scientific terms with clearly defined meanings. Language is fluid, and is most meaningful when there is a shared understanding of intent between the speaker and the listener. Case in point - when I googled IBD [a term I had never heard of], I had to change to "IBD finance" before "irritable bowel syndrome" dropped off the top page.